# Is there an Environment Variable that contains the clipboard contents?

Tags: bash, command-line, clipboard

Is there a Bash environment variable (say `$CLIPBOARD` or similar) that contains the current contents of the clipboard?

The specific example is to see the top 20 lines of a file whose path I have just copied into the clipboard.

1. Copy path with `Ctrl-C`
2. Switch to terminal
3. Type `more`, `Ctrl-V`

**UPDATE:** I'm running on CentOS 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a bash environment variable. For your platform (which you don't specify) you may be able to use a command line tool like [xclip](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/565) or one of the many Windows utilities (google for "windows clipboard command line").

Answer (score 2):

You might look into [xclip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip) or [pbcopy](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html)/pbpaste (Mac OS X).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know exactly what you are trying to accomplish.  Check out the following article and see if it helps: [Remotely transferring clipboard data using netcat and bash](http://katamari.ssec.wisc.edu/resources/scriptonomicon/remotely-transferring-clipboard-data-using-netcat-and-bash)

Update: If you are using OSX, try using [pbcopy](http://www.ss64.com/osx/pbcopy.html) & [pbpaste](http://www.ss64.com/osx/pbpaste.html) to copy and paste data from the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

This requires an additional command-line utility, but it looks like what you describe:

[Command Line to Clipboard](http://linuxtidbits.wordpress.com/2008/02/22/command-line-to-clipboard/)

Answer (score 0):

Using xclip combined with Readline bindings in Bash - a bit of a hack, but it works

http://bash-hackers.org/wiki/doku.php/snipplets/xclip