# How do I capture bash output to the Mac OS X clipboard?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, clipboard

Is it possible to capture bash output to the OS X clipboard?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96024/is-it-possible-to-send-the-contents-of-a-text-file-to-the-clipboard-from-the-comm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064762/is-there-an-environment-variable-that-contains-the-clipboard-contents

Answer (score 300, accepted):

The [pbcopy](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html) command does this.

For example, this puts the output from `ls` on the clipboard/pasteboard:

```
ls | pbcopy
```

And [pbpaste](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbpaste.1.html) does the reverse, writing to stdout from the clipboard:

```
pbpaste > ls.txt
```

You can use both together to filter content on the clipboard - here's a [rot13](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=2003050204544799):

```
pbpaste | tr 'a-zA-Z' 'n-za-mN-ZA-M' | pbcopy
```

Answer (score 7):

In case you want to capture error messages, this will work:

```
cmd 2>&1  | pbcopy
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `pbcopy` command:

```
pbcopy < ./path/to/file/or/output/stream
```

Comment: Good to have this in your pocket, though that's not really "capturing bash output" so much as streaming a file, right?  As compared to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1753127/1108305.