# How to Copy a File to Clipboard in Python (Mac)

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to find out an answer to the above question - I have already tried `shutil`, which to my knowledge, does not work because I do not want to copy the file to a destination.

Currently using Pyperclip module for text to the clipboard, but this does not work with actual local files.

My end goal is to copy two files to my clipboard using python code, then be able to paste them into an email.

Comment: What is your Python code for composing email?

Comment: I don't have python code for composing email just yet - I am still working on that. The program is copying text (and hopefully files) to the clipboard, then I go to outlook and paste it into an email.

Comment: Open the file, read it, use Pyperclip to put the contents on the clipboard?

Comment: I'd advise you to start from the end: from composing email. You can use `mock`/`stub` for the __actual__ file contents, e.g. let the "copied" text always be "hello world". Then, you'll replace this "hello world" either with filepath / or with file contents / or with whatever your email composing code will require.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jason, but they are .pdf files that I need the recipient to be able to download themselves and print off if they would like to.

Comment: Sorry olha I do not quite understand that.

Comment: Is it necessary to use `python`? If you don't have any preprocessing code, merely copy,  yoou can try `pbcopy` (on MacOS) to copy the content of file to clipboard: `pbcopy < [path to your file]`. Then, paste it anywhere you want with `Command + v`. You can see more [here](https://superuser.com/questions/298227/how-to-send-the-contents-of-a-text-file-to-the-clipboard-from-the-command-line-i) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1753110/how-do-i-capture-bash-output-to-the-mac-os-x-clipboard).

Comment: That's interesting Hoa thank you - can I use pbcopy inside of IDLE? I am new to programming so I am unsure of the relationship between the terminal and programming environments.

Comment: @MSawers you do it in the terminal. Just open the terminal, write the command: `pbcopy < [path to your file]. For example, I need to copy the content of file `data.csv` in my Desktop to clipboard, I will to this: `pbcopy ~/Desktop/data.csv`. Then, I paste the content anywhere I like by the shortcut: `Command + V`.

Comment: However, as you said, the files are in `pdf` format, I think you need some preprocessing to read the file. `pbcopy` simply copy text, not the format.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this will solve for pasting into an email, but I came across this question while looking for how to copy stuff to the clipboard in macOS and have since found a solution that works for me. I figured I'd post it in case anyone else happens across this post with similar needs.

As mentioned in this question's comments, I came across Pyperclip. However I don't want any external dependencies. So, I took a peak at how Pyperclip implemented copy/paste and it's relatively simple. See **[here](https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/blob/4ae5b1cfa366a6d4227d80b636bb4978bcbb5b06/src/pyperclip/__init__.py#L115)**.

The short of it is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess

# copy
def pbcopy(txt):
    task = subprocess.Popen(
        ['pbcopy'],
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        close_fds=True
    )
    task.communicate(input=txt.encode('utf-8'))

# paste
def pbpaste():
    task = subprocess.Popen(
        ['pbpaste'],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        close_fds=True
    )
    stdout, stderr = task.communicate()
    return(stdout.decode('utf-8'))
```

Hopefully this solves [@MSawers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13959938/msawers) question and if not hopefully someone else will find this useful.

Comment: just saw this now. thank you so much for answering!